# spanM, takeWhileM in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, higher-order-functions

I have following problem: Given a `[String]` and `String->IO Int`. So I can make a transformation (map) and get `[IO Int]`. Now, I have to do two things -- perfrorm that actions, from start, until result is positive and I need to know, was all list processed.
I am forbidded to process after first non-positive result.

`takeWhileM` do not answer second question(length compraison is too impractical), and `spanM` perform forbidden `IO`.

Of course, I can write recursive function myself, but I want to do it in Haskell way, with all good of high-order functions.

Suggestions? Probably, use completely another approach?
Task above is a bit simplified task from my project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `allM` from [the `monad-loops` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.3.1.0):

```
Prelude Control.Monad.Loops> let xs = ["a", "bb", "ccc", "dddd", "eeeee"]
Prelude Control.Monad.Loops> let f x = putStrLn x >> return (length x)
Prelude Control.Monad.Loops> let p x = x < 2
Prelude Control.Monad.Loops> allM (fmap p . f) xs
a
bb
False
```

There's also an `allM` in `Control.Monad.ListM`, but it's not appropriately lazy—it will continue to perform computations after you hit a positive result.

(I'm with you on this, by the way—I hate writing one-off recursive functions.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the functions `takeWhileM` and `spanM` (and neither is [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/)) (**edit:** as per comment, they can be found in [Control.Monad.ListM](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monadlist/0.0.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-ListM.html)).

Given that, I think the best thing for you to do is to make a one-off function to perform this task. If it later turns out that you need to write code to do something similar, *then* you can factor out the common parts and re-use them. There's nothing wrong with writing one-off code in general, it's code *duplication* that's bad.

There are a few ways to write the function you want - one possible way is like this:

```
process :: [IO Int] -> IO Bool
process []     = return True
process [a]    = a >> return True
process (a:as) = do
    n <- a
    if n > 0
        then return False
        else process as
```

Comment: Control.Monad.ListM. Well, something like this. I am not saying writing code is bad, but haskell libraries so good, so I am in doubt nobody implemented it before me. 

And, code, that use standart library is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

@illusionoflife: I don't see how using `takeWhileM` would improve on @Chris's solution.

For example:

```
import Control.Monad.ListM

process :: [IO Int] -> IO Bool
process as = do
  taken <- takeWhileM (>>= return . (<= 0)) as
  return (length taken >= length as - 1)
```

(Code not verified!)

@Chris's looks more readable, among other things because in his solution we don't need to figure out if we should use `>=` or `==`. Besides, since I call `length` we can't use it on an infinite input list.